# How to display a dialog box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dialog

I need recommendations on something. I would like to display a box to the user a list of all the processes that are going on during a long process. The user clicks one button and the process takes about 30 seconds. What is the best way to display information about what is actually going on? Im pretty new to programming and any help will be greatly appreciated. Im using c#, asp.net, and visual studio 2010. If that is not enough let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Is this during a Webforms postback or are you performing an ajax callback? If a callback, then you could show an animated "Processing..." type graphic and then hide it when the callback completes. On a postback, I do not see a way.

Comment: Im not performing an ajax callback. Even if theres a box that pops up that shows information of any kind. That would be awesome. Im just not sure where to begin on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the `ModalPopupExtender` in the [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/).

You can also try creating the dialog with jQuery. If you decide to go that route, check out the jQuery UI dialog:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/